# Can I query a DateTime in a SQL Server view using timezone?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a DateTime field in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have some views that query that field such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TransactionDate) = 'April 10 2012'.
```

The servertime is set to texas time, and I want to query this data using EST.  In other words

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE TransactionDate = 'April 10 2012 Eastern Standard Time'
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

"DATETIMEOFFSET Datatype

Currently when saving the date and time in a column, it will not indicate what time zone that date and time belongs to. This can be especially important when you are dealing with data including several different countries with different time zones. The new datatype `DATETIMEOFFSET` defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that has time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.  The following script illustrates the usage of the `DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype.

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIMEOFFSET(0)

SET @dt = '2007-10-29 22:50:55 -1:00'

DECLARE @dt1 DATETIMEOFFSET(0)

SET @dt1 = '2007-10-29 22:50:55 +5:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,@dt,@Dt1)
```

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/datetime-2008/

Comment: So this would be a different way for me to store the TransactionDate rather than querying on the one that I already have?  i.e. - to use this method I would need to either change the type of the field I already have, or add another field yes?

Comment: Is there a solution for SQL Server 2000, which doesn't appear to have the datatimeoffset type?

Comment: @kaes No you use the date time you already have a manipulate it.  Take a look at the link provided above and that should help.

Comment: @scorpdaddy as far as I know this was added in sql server 2008. Hopefully someone else can chime in on sql server 2000.